# How to parse the address returned from GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to use the Android Google Places API to get suggestions for addresses. The query code looks like this:

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(googleApiClient,
        constraint, latLngBounds, null);
```

However, the API returns a type [AutocompletePrediction](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompletePrediction), and it only contains the description (the address as a full string) and a placeId (looks like it can be used to query for the actual place information).

Is there an easy way to retrieve more specific information around this prediction, such as address, city, state, etc., without doing a separate query for each result?

Comment: Unfortunately not. See [my related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39181135/383414) for a bit more information, and a link to the issue logged against Google requesting such information.

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/) will help you for sure . In this tutorial the user just have to enter a string then google API's will return a json data(list of suggestion according to the string given to API) which will be parsed and can be seen in the drop down menu of the search box . I think this is what you need

Comment: In the tutorial the returned data is also only the description and not the broken down pieces (address, city, etc.). :(